# dynamic cast to non-derived object in order to call a function works?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, downcast

I read in a C++ book that you can use dynamic_cast to downcast a pointer to a base object to a derived object pointer, if the object it points to actually is that of the derived type. The format is `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(basePointer)`. Furthermore, I read on this website that dynamic_cast should return a null pointer if the object it points to cannot be converted to the derived class type.

However, I recently tried having a pointer to a plain object with a virtual function downcast to an object that's derived from a different class, in order to call one of that class' functions. To my surprise, it worked:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Object {
    public:
        virtual ~Object () {}
};

class Base {
    public:
        virtual void doSomething () {
            cout << "Done something!" << endl;
        }
};

class Derived: public Base {
    public:
        virtual void doSomething () {
            cout << "You done goofed!" << endl;
        }
        void printFoo () {
            cout << "Foo" << endl;
        }

    private:
        int x;
};

int main () {
    Object o;
    Object* p = &o;

    if(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p))
        cout << "Yep, baby is derived!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Isn't derived." << endl;

    dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p)->printFoo();


    return 0;
}
```

Here, Base is a base class type designed to be used polymorphically (that is, it contains a virtual function), and Derived is a class type derived from Base. Object is just a plain class that is not related to either class, but its destructor is made virtual so that it can be used polymorphically. I'll explain the purpose of Derived::x in a moment. In the main function, an Object is created and a pointer to Object is assigned to its address. It checks whether Derived is a descendant of that pointer, and prints whether it is or it isn't. Then it casts that pointer to a pointer of type Derived, and Derived's printFoo function is called.

This shouldn't work, but it does. When I run it, it displays "Isn't derived," so it clearly understands that Obect is not Derived from Base, but then it prints "Foo" on the screen and exits without error. However, if I add the line `x = 1;` to the printFoo function, it exits with a Segmentation fault, as it's trying to assign a variable which doesn't exist in that object. Furthermore, this only seems to work with non-virtual functions. If I try to call the virtual function doSomething, for instance, I get the Segmentation fault before "You done goofed!" is ever printed out.

What's going on here? Shouldn't `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p)` return a null pointer, so that trying to call printFoo from that would automatically cause an error? Why is that working when it shouldn't?

Comment: It doesn't work. It is *undefined behaviour*, that's all.

Comment: _'return a null pointer, so that trying to call printFoo from that would automatically cause an error?'_ No, dereferencing a `NULL` pointer doesn't automatically cause an error, you'll have to check before calling.

Comment: +1 for a "Why does this work?" question; a welcome contrast to the many vague "It doesn't work!" questions on this site :)

Comment: haha, thanks, and thanks for all the answers I've received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already established that `dynamic_cast` is returning a NULL pointer, so the real question is why function calls on a NULL object pointer appear to work in some cases but not others.

In *ALL* of these cases you're getting undefined behavior. Just remember that undefined doesn't always mean crash - sometimes you get perfectly reasonable results. You just can't rely on it.

Here's an explanation based on what's *probably* going on, but there are no guarantees it will work the same way tomorrow, much less when you change the optimization settings or get a new version of the compiler.

`printFoo` isn't virtual, so there's no need to use a vtable to access it. `doSomething` is virtual so it *does* need the vtable. A NULL pointer doesn't have a vtable so calling `doSomething` blows up immediately.

`printFoo` doesn't use any of the members of the object until you add the `x = 1` line to it. As long as the compiler doesn't generate any code that accesses the `this` pointer, it's likely to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It works because

```
dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p)->printFoo();
```

returns a `null` pointer as expected, but the `null` pointer *is of type Derived*. When it calls `printFoo`, it works because `printFoo` does not use any member variable, in which case it would refer to `this` for using that variable, and would crash for dereferencing `null` pointer. Since no member variable is used, no reference to `this`, no problem( that's why it gives segfault when u use `x` in the method).

It is same as following simple code:

```
class A{
  public:
   int x;
   void f1(){}
   void f2(){x=1;}
}

 A* x=nulptr;
 x->f1(); // will work
 x->f2(); // UB
```

Comment: Technically speaking *both* functions are UB, it's just that one is more likely to not exhibit any symptoms.

Comment: +1 @MarkRansom, You are right. I was just explaining **why** first one works now, no guarantee it will work in future.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing a `null` pointer without using any actual object state, which is safe though meaningless.

If you change Derived::printFoo() to the following, you'll actually be in "undefined behavior territory", and will very likely segfault:

```
void printFoo () {
  cout << "Foo: " << x << endl;
}
```

For what it's worth, using references instead of pointers will make this throw an exception if you'd rather propagate the failure outward than test and deal with it locally:

```
dynamic_cast<Derived &>(*p).printFoo(); // kaboom! throws std::bad_cast
```

Comment: Calling it "safe" is going a little too far. It's *likely* to be safe, but not guaranteed - it's still undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom Which part falls into UB if it can be statically determined that no member state will be touched?

Comment: I think dereferencing a NULL pointer is UB by definition even if the pointer is only used for static type determination.